# Mavericks entering accents into Chrome?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, internationalization

So starting in Lion, you have been able to enter accents by simply holding down certain keys and selecting your accent.  However, in Chrome when I hold down on a key it enters a second one: For instance, if I were trying to type état, it would come out as eétat; an extra e would be entered for no reason.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: More details on what steps you're using to type accented characters into Chrome might help formulating a more detailed answer. Also, this could be an issue that depends on your language settings, keyboard country, etc.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem.  Where in Chrome does this happen?  Does it happen in all web pages?

Comment: Yes it does.  Try, say, google translate

Answer (score 1):

I am able to successfully type "état" into Chrome on Mavericks by typing the sequence option-e, e.

In other words, hold down the option key and press the letter 'e'. Then press the letter 'e' again. The accented letter only appears once.

Comment: However, this solution is specific to this accent.  For others, I would have to memorize other keyboard combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down a key, then press digit for selected character or click on selected character by mouse.